# Read xml inside xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I got this XML document with an XML-string defined inside an element:

```
<HIT>
<FIELD NAME="xmlstring">
&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
&lt;kontaktpersoner&gt;&lt;person&gt;&lt;funksjon&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Økonomi]]&gt;&lt;/funksjon&gt;&lt;tittel&gt;      &lt;![CDATA[regnskapsansv.]]&gt;&lt;/tittel&gt;&lt;email&gt;&lt;![CDATA[test@test.no]]&gt;&lt;/email&gt;&lt;navn&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Test Test]]&gt;&lt;/navn&gt;&lt;/person&gt;&lt;person&gt;&lt;funksjon&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Leder]]&gt;&lt;/funksjon&gt;&lt;tittel&gt;&lt;![CDATA[adm. dir.]]&gt;&lt;/tittel&gt;&lt;email&gt;&lt;![CDATA[test2@test.no]]&gt;&lt;/email&gt;&lt;navn&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Test2 Test]]&gt;&lt;/navn&gt;&lt;/person&gt;&lt;/kontaktpersoner&gt;
</FIELD>
</HIT>
```

The XML inside the element with the `"xmlstring"` attribute is escaped with `&lt;` and `&gt;` and is read as string and not XML.

How do I make it possible to use this with XPath in XSLT?

Comment: I don't think "attribute" in your question refers to the NAME attribute of the FIELD element, but what does it refer to then? Can you clarify you question? Also, the XML processing instruction in the middle of your XML is either outright invalid or at least very strange. According to the XML specificaton it SHOULD appear in the beginning and MUST appear before anything else.

Comment: This is not valid XML. The XML declaration must begin at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

If you can switch xslt processors, Saxon has a [parse](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/parse.html) function that would allow you use import the embedded document into a variable and process it like you would your input document.

Answer (score 1):

> The XML inside the "xmlstring" attribute is escaped with `&lt;` and `&gt;` and is read as string and not XML.

Think about it... Isn't that precisely how things should be? How is your XSLT supposed to know that your XML contains XML within XML (and that nested XML is not even within a `CDATA` section) ?

Comment: Well, actually, it's not XML at all.

Comment: @John: Actually, it *represents* an XML string. I think you misunderstand the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done in a one-step process in XSLT.

Your only chance is to extract the document string, parse it into a separate XML document, and take it from there.

As an alternative solution, you cold write a transformation like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FIELD[@NAME='xmlstring']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />

      <!-- now this is somewhat brittle, I would not really recommend 
           it for production use, but maybe it helps nevertheless -->
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., '&lt;?xml')">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '?&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces:

```
<HIT>
  <FIELD NAME="xmlstring">
    <kontaktpersoner>
      <person>
        <funksjon><![CDATA[Økonomi]]></funksjon>
        <tittel><![CDATA[regnskapsansv.]]></tittel>
        <email><![CDATA[test@test.no]]></email>
        <navn><![CDATA[Test Test]]></navn>
      </person>
      <person>
        <funksjon><![CDATA[Leder]]></funksjon>
        <tittel><![CDATA[adm. dir.]]></tittel>
        <email><![CDATA[test2@test.no]]></email>
        <navn><![CDATA[Test2 Test]]></navn>
      </person>
    </kontaktpersoner>
  </FIELD>
</HIT>
```

Which then can be used like a normal XML document in a second step.